# Cannot start MySQL service on linux RHEL when pointing datadir to mounted ecryptfs folder

Tags: mysql, linux

I moved the data directory for MySQL to an ecryptfs encrypted folder.
When I run service mysqld start as root, the service will not start.

```
[Warning] Can't create test file /mysql/ip-172-31-29-184.lower-test
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

When it used to start before my encrypting the folder

```
ls -lZ /mysql outputs

drwx------. mysql mysql unconfined_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
```

now

```
ls -lZ /mysql outputs
drwx------. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:ecryptfs_t:s0  mysql
```

I think the issue is with how I mounted the encrypted directory.  
mount -t ecryptfs /mysql /mysql

mount outputs

```
/mysql on /mysql type ecryptfs
 (rw,ecryptfs_sig=6860c372da7bc418,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)
```

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago), MySQL 5.6.22

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: does it work well without encryption?.. i think you may need to change ownership recursively using chown -R mysql:mysql for whole directories and then can try.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Yes, it works if I don't use encryption.  The folder and sub directories are all owned by mysql.

Comment: Looks like you have bad selinux labels on the folder. Before encryption I see `mysqld_db_t` and after encryption this is gone. Instead of it `ecryptfs_t` is present.

Try turning selinux off or better - set it temporarily into permissive mode with `setenforce 0`. If mysql starts, check selinux logs what it is complainging about.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the MySQL server owner is MySQL:MySQL using `chown -R mysql:mysql /mysql` and the permission level is 755 for everything except `my.cnf` 644. `chmod 644 my.cnf` then execute the following commands after changing the information inside `my.cnf` to the correct one.

```
cd /mysql/bin
./mysqld --defaults-file=/mysql/my.cnf --user=mysql &
```

**Edit to answer the comment below**
To shutdown MySQL safely without killing the SID (or PID) you can use one of the following commands:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown
```

or

```
sudo mysqld stop
```

note: in-case you can more than SID running you need to specify the port for it.

Comment: Hi Ahmad,  Thank you for your suggestion.
I changed the permission for /mysql to 755.  The owner and group are mysql:mysql
There is no bin folder in /mysql. /mysql is my data directory is and I modified /etc/my.cfn (datadir=/mysql) to point to that. I tried starting the service after the permission change but I am still getting the same error.

Here is a listing of what is in /mysql folder.
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 mysql mysql   56 Dec 23 00:00 auto.cnf
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql mysql 4096 Dec 23 00:00 mysql
drwxr-xr-x.  2 mysql mysql 4096 Dec 23 00:00 performance_schema
Thank you again.

Comment: did you installed MySQL via yum or apt-get command? or extract the compressed file?

Comment: Hi Ahmad, Thank you! I installed via yum and I found the mysqld file to start it. This worked - ./mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --user=mysql &

Comment: Hi Ahmad, how do I safely shutdown this instance of mysql short of using killing the pid? Is there anyway I can start mysql for the encrypted folders using the service mysqld commands?  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Grace, please refer to my edit in the answer section above

Comment: Hi Ahmad, mysqladmin -u root -p shutdown works! Thank you so much again.